# iPhone utility application, Label text does not update in FLipSideView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uistoryboard

I am using the utility application template in Xcode with a main and a flipside view.
In the main view I have a property label called L0. I am trying to copy that label on the flipside view.
On the flipside view, I have declared

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

It is synthesized in the .m file

```
@synthesize label = _label;
```

and my prepareForFegue method is :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {

     FlipsideViewController *fsv = (FlipsideViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
     fsv.label = self.L0;
     fsv.delegate = self; 
}}
```

However the text of the label on the flipsideview doesn't change although if I NSLog fsv.label.text in prepareForSegue I see that it is properly set to the value of L0.text.

Any Idea on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point of prepareForSegue your destination view controller has been created, but the view hasn't loaded. Therefore whatever you assign to the label is overwritten when the view *is* loaded. You can confirm this by logging the label property before you do anything with it - it will be nil.

The destination VC should have a string property instead, which you set in prepareForSegue with your desired text. You then set the label's text from this string property in viewWillAppear.